# How to upload PDF from Front-End and post automatically?

Tags: plugins, posts, front-end, blog, pdf

I have a medical client and they want to upload and post pdf automatically.

So I stumbled upon [frontend uploader](https://wordpress.org/plugins/frontend-uploader/), which allows users to upload and post an image to a blog post. It does however post with a pdf, but it goes straight to the media library.

So a alternative solution I came up with is getting the pdf to jpeg, and then just upload the jpeg along with the blog post.

Comment: What is the desired functionality? In WP PDFs do go in the Media Library; they aren't standalone Posts.

Comment: @WebElaine The desired functionality is to have the own medical staff upload pdf's from a front end uploader, and then have the pdf file display to a page / post automatically so the rest of the medical staff can see their work schedule.

Comment: Sounds like you might want to create a CPT and have that CPT's `single-cpt.php` template automatically look for a PDF among the post's attachments, then embed/display the first PDF it finds (which may require another plugin).

Answer (score 1):

I use Postie to allow non-technical users to post items via email, including pictures/media. Easy enough to set up; checks email every xx minutes (several choices). When an email is found, it converts that to a post. Works well, and is well-used.

https://wordpress.org/plugins/postie/